# How to include resources in jar

Tags: maven

I need to include contents of resources folder into my jar. I know to include from src/main/resources folder. But my structure is as follow
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qELCQ.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way is to just adjust to the standard directory layout and move your files to `src/main/resources`. Convention over configuration. Makes everyone's life easier.

Comment: Instead of putting files in src/main/resources, I want the same structure. Any help on how to include this structure in jar.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the folders for your resources:

```
    <build>
      ...
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
          <directory>other/optional/resource/path</directory>
        </resource>
      </resources>
     ...
     </build>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to stick with the *src/main/resources* convention but if you insist you can use *maven-antrun-plugin* and create a task to copy the files into your *target/classes* folder.